# OpenStack VM not able to access internet

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I have installed openstack using [devstack](http://devstack.org/). I am able to create the instance, I can also login into the instance via ssh, but the VM is not getting the internet access. I have also given the free range of IP address to the instance. I am only able to ping on the machine in which the VM is installed. ping request is not even reaching the gateway.

Thanks

Comment: I think best place for this question is openstack mailing list. Stackoverflow entertains question related to programming and software development only. Please see the FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq